# Calling super.paintcomponent(g) in class doesn't work

Tags: java

before i ask this question i have checked other people questions to see if anyone have the solution, i have tried some, but it doesn't working. And i'm asking you that maybe there is something else that my program need than the others doesn't.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this small peace of code?

```
package DrawPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class DrawPanel
{
    private int getHeight()
    { return 0; }
    private int getWidth() 
    { return 0; }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {   
        super.paintComponent(g);    // line of error => paintComponent
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        g.drawLine(0, 0,width,height);
        g.drawLine(0, height, width, 0);
    }
}
```

And the other code here to run it:

```
package DrawPanel;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class DrawPanelTest
{
    public static void main ( String [] Args)
    {
        DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();

        JFrame application = new JFrame();

        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.add(panel); //Line of error => add
        application.setSize(500,500);
        application.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Now if i remove the error lines, the app will work, but NOT 100%.
It will not show the draw lines that i did. It will open me only a window. How to make the app works right?? **Thank you.**

Comment: Your `DrawPanel` class does not extend any other class.  Therefore, `super` is meaningless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {   
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        g.drawLine(0, 0,width,height);
        g.drawLine(0, height, width, 0);
    }
}
```

You should extend `JPanel`

`super` refers to the immediate parents property. So in your case you can't call super because DrawPanel doesn't have a parent. You can solve that by adding `extends JPanel`, which will also solve your `.add()` problem in your `main` method. .add() expects a `Component`

Comment: by putting this code it gives me 2 more errors.
getHeight()
getWeidth()

Comment: Ok, it worked. but i had to remove the following code: private int getHeight() { return 0; }

    private int getWidth() { return 0; }